# Highlighting a matched regex in a contentEditable div on input. Having the caret stay where it belongs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, contenteditable

After emphasizing an email address in my `<div contentEditable="true">` I'm having trouble setting to Carot to where it was or where it should be.

It seems to jump to the beginning of the Node's firstChild instead of jumping out of the `<strong>` tag to the right.

```
$('[contenteditable]').on("input", function() {
    $this = $(this);

    var re = /([a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)\b)/gi;
    //'

    var result = $this.html().match(re) || [];

    if (!result.compare(_emailArray) || result.length > _emailCount || result.length < _emailCount) {       
        var range = getCaretPos();
        $this.html(function() {
            var content = $this.html();
            content = content.replace(/(<(\/*strong)>)/ig,"");
            content = content.replace(re, "<strong>$1</strong>");
            return content;
        });
        setCaretPos(range);

        _emailCount = result.length;
        _emailArray = result;
    }
});
```

So the problem lays in the `getCaretPos()` and `setCaretPos()` functions

```
function getCaretPos(){ 
    var sel = window.getSelection();    
    var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    return range;
}
function setCaretPos(range){
    range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart(range.startContainer,range.startOffset);
    range.setEnd(range.endContainer,range.endOffset);
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.addRange(range);
}
```

To be honest, I didn't quite get the concept of ranges. That is what I should be using here, right? those two functions are patched together from a couple of snippets i found.

Any chance somebody could explain ranges or even fix the code? By the way, if somebody has an idea for wrapping an email address in `strong` tags without doing it for all email addresses each time, let me know!

I appreciate any advices, snippets and ideas. Thanks!

Comment: I feel this is just the start of your headaches. Having messed around with ranges enough in the past I am not going to even attempt to provide you with a solution. But you may find that adding the `<strong>` tag is in fact messing with your DOM to the point that your caret offset is no longer valid

Comment: thanks. that is what i figured. even `$this.html( $this.html() );` instead of adding `<strong>` messes up everything. even though I basically don't do anything...